# Change the highlighting behaviour of the box select tool in Bokeh?

Tags: python, bokeh

I have a scatter plot made with black circles. When the box select tool is used the circles outside the box are automatically coloured a semitransparent blue.

Is there a way, within the API, to keep the outside circles black and change the colour of the inside circles? If I have two linked scatter plots, is there a way to have the highlighted circles on each a plot a different colour?

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show

N = 100
max = 100
x = np.random.random(size=N) * max
y = np.random.random(size=N) * max
output_file("scatter.html")

p = figure(tools="box_select", width=400, height=400, x_range=(0,100), y_range=(0,100))
p.circle(x, y, size=10, fill_color="black", line_color=None)

show(p)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the `selection_glyph` and `nonselection_glyph` properties of the circle renderer. See the [manual](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/0.10.0/docs/user_guide/styling.html#selected-unselected-glyphs) or [How to set properties of selected/unselected glyphs in bokeh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34210614/how-to-set-properties-of-selected-unselected-glyphs-in-bokeh) for more details.

You can use different colors for each plot, the visual properties aren't shared by the selection.

[image]

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file
from bokeh.models import Circle

N = 100
max = 100
x = np.random.random(size=N) * max
y = np.random.random(size=N) * max

p = figure(tools="box_select", width=400, height=400, x_range=(0,100), y_range=(0,100))
r = p.circle(x, y, size=10, fill_color="black", line_color=None)
r.selection_glyph = Circle(fill_color="orange", line_color=None)
r.nonselection_glyph = Circle(fill_color="black", line_color=None)

output_file("scatter.html")
show(p)
```